# redirecting rich.inspect to file?

Tags: python, rich

I am trying to troubleshoot why program receiving one set of parameters works (call it **v1**), while another call with *almost the same parameters* fails (call that **v2**).

So I want to diff some complex nested data structures.  Trying a yaml dump resulted in errors (there are weakrefs and SQL connection objects).  So I used `rich.inspect` in the pdb debugger and found some issues - rich is smart enough not to get itself in trouble.  So now, I want to dump this out to a text file instead.

Is there a more elegant way than redirecting `sys.stdout`?  The code below works, but it's fairly ugly near `with open("capture2.txt","w") as sys.stdout:`.

`cat capture2.txt` prints substantially the same output as the rich.inspect, including the colors.  So, that's good, but is there a cleaner way to send rich.inspect to a file?  The `console` argument looks like it might, but then again it looks more like a way to specify color and terminal behavior, rather than allowing for redirection.

```
from rich import inspect
import sys
#just a simple way to get some complexity cheap
from types import SimpleNamespace

foo = SimpleNamespace(
    a = 1,
    name = "Foo",
    bar = SimpleNamespace(b=2, name="Bar!", di = dict(a=1,b=2,c=[1,2,3]))
)
#OK, simple prints to screen
inspect(foo)


# is there a better way here 

print("redirect stdout")
#save stdout
bup = sys.stdout
with open("capture2.txt","w") as sys.stdout:
    inspect(foo)
# restore stdout
sys.stdout = bup

#if I don't restore `sys.stdout` from `bup` => IOError
print("coucou")
```

#### Screenshot of output:

[image]

p.s. To make diffing easier I did get rid of some of the terminal codes (color and font-related) by using `rich.inspect(x,console = Console(force_terminal=False))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Read The Fine Manual:

There are a lot of parameters for `Console`.  I managed to miss `file`:

```
class Console:
    """A high level console interface.

    Args:
        color_system (str, optional): The color system supported by your terminal,
            either ``"standard"``, ``"256"`` or ``"truecolor"``. Leave as ``"auto"`` to autodetect.
        force_terminal (Optional[bool], optional): Enable/disable terminal control codes, or None to auto-detect terminal. Defaults to None.  
        ...
      file (IO, optional): A file object where the console should write to. Defaults to stdout.
        quiet (bool, Optional): Boolean to suppress all output. Defaults to False.
```

So...

```
with open("capture2.txt","w") as fo:
    console = Console(force_terminal=False,file=fo)
    inspect(foo,console=console)
```

I'll leave that out, hopefully someone will find it useful later.